# What is the standard 'trunk' site equivalent for Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, trunk

We are moving to Mercurial from Subversion. With Subversion, we have http://trunk.myproduct.com for testing purposes. I am wondering what the standard name for a trunk-like site is for Mercurial. 'trunk' seems like a Subversion term. http://default.myproduct.com is the most obvious name, but is that what people generally use? I am looking for the most standard convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a convention.  People using Mercurial generally have more repositories.

I've seen a "central" repository named as bits.example.com, example.com/hg, example.com/branches/1.x, and so on.

Name it whatever you like - just make sure you have a standard convention for which changes go to which repository, and when.